# AWS IoT Core - MQTT Test Client not receiving full JSON payload

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt

Currently am successfully sending short messages to the AWS IoT Core MQTT test client using an Arduino MKR WiFi 1010 and the libraries described [here](https://docs.arduino.cc/tutorials/mkr-wifi-1010/securely-connecting-an-arduino-mkr-wifi-1010-to-aws-iot-core). (The code and steps needed to be followed can all be found within the link.)

I have had success in also moving this data from the MQTT client to an AWS Dynamo DB table.

The problem arises when I try to send a payload longer than ~250 characters long. I know it is possible as I have sent 400 characters before but I am unsure of what I am doing wrong/differently.

Comment: Show us how you are calling `beginMessage` - are you passing a `size`? (if not the default buffer size will be 256 - you can change this with [`setTxPayloadSize`](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoMqttClient/blob/master/src/MqttClient.cpp#L815C18-L815C34) but if you know the size in advance it's better to pass it).

Comment: 'mqttClient.beginMessage("arduino/outgoing");'

That is how I am calling the function. I was unware of how you could modify the size. I will try to run this function now. I am not passing a size.

Comment: I tried to alter a variable called '_tx_payload_buffer_size' and that did not work. I am struggling to find the exact location that I can change this default size.

Comment: The [link](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoMqttClient/blob/master/src/MqttClient.cpp#L815C18-L815C34) I provided was to the ArduinoMqttClient source. I'd guess you have an old version of the library (the function was added just over a year ago in v0.1.6).

Comment: Thank you! Super late response but you asking if I passed the function a size made me realize there was a size to pass in the first place. So you asking me a question helped me learn a bit more about he MQTT message structures and I was able to solve the issue on my own. All I had to do was dig deeper in the library files and set a defaulted payload size to what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: No worries - added an answer as I don't think this is something that's obvious to most users of the library.

Answer (score 0):

On the wire each MQTT message has a fixed header that contains:

- byte 1 - Packet type and Flags - For a `PUBLISH` the packet type is 50 and flags are things like the QOS level.
- byte 2... (variable length) - Remaining Length - the number of bytes remaining within the current packet, including data in the variable header and the payload.

Because of this a client needs to know the total packet size before it can transmit a message. With a publish message (where the payload size may vary significantly) there are two possible approaches for a library:

1. Wait until the whole message is available before sending (so we know the size).
2. Allow the user to provide the size (allowing the body to be transmitted in multiple chunks).

`ArduinoMqttClient` supports both through a range of [`beginMessage`](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoMqttClient/blob/master/src/MqttClient.h#L62) signatures:

```c
int beginMessage(const char* topic, unsigned long size, bool retain = false, uint8_t qos = 0, bool dup = false);
int beginMessage(const String& topic, unsigned long size, bool retain = false, uint8_t qos = 0, bool dup = false);
int beginMessage(const char* topic, bool retain = false, uint8_t qos = 0, bool dup = false);
int beginMessage(const String& topic, bool retain = false, uint8_t qos = 0, bool dup = false);
```

If you pass a `size` then the message will be streamed (see [here](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoMqttClient/blob/master/src/MqttClient.cpp#L181) and [here](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoMqttClient/blob/master/src/MqttClient.cpp#L181)). This means that the header will be sent when you call `beginMessage` and then each call to `write` will result in data being sent out. If you know the size of the data to be sent this is the best approach, because it avoids the need to copy the data into a buffer.

If no `size` is passed then each call to `write` [copies data into a buffer](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoMqttClient/blob/master/src/MqttClient.cpp#L675) (and it's sent when `endMessage` is called). Should the data passed in exceed the capacity of the buffer (by [default](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoMqttClient/blob/master/src/MqttClient.cpp#L32) 128 or 256 bytes) then data will be [lost](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoMqttClient/blob/master/src/MqttClient.cpp#L675). In more recent versions of the library you can set the buffer size with [`void setTxPayloadSize(unsigned short size)`](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoMqttClient/blob/master/src/MqttClient.h#L108C3-L108C46).